# ClamAV and Metasploit

Tags: linux, virus, metasploit

I removed the Metasploit framework with the command dnf remove
metasploit-framework and I did a full scan of my Linux distribution
with Clam AV and 4 infected files are detected:

- /var/cache/PackageKit/29/metadata/metasploit/repodata/6727fbd7ca119ba388385979b8a37
  filelists.xml.gz: Win.Trojan.Maljava-2 FOUND
- /var/cache/PackageKit/28/metadata/metasploit/repodata/6727fbd7ca119ba388385979b8a37
  filelists.xml.gz: Win.Trojan.Maljava-2 FOUND
- /var/cache/PackageKit/27/metadata/metasploit/repodata/fcafa72dab0eff7cceaaffca3bb88
  filelists.xml.gz: Win.Trojan.Maljava-2 FOUND
- /var/cache/dnf/metasploit-
  8563bff355959463/repodata/d424996864f39818946d154055f4841acb08192665beb9c91e7cc80e1
  filelists.xml.gz: Win.Trojan.Maljava-2 FOUND

Are these files harmless?

Comment: I would imagine due to the nature of Metasploit, files it installs, are often identified as being malicious but in reality they are perfectly safe.  You should use multiple AV products in order to verify the files are safe or malicous.  In the end you installed Metasploit so I would imagine the source of the files you installed on your system.

Comment: Analyzing those files they are simple compressed xml files so it should be a false positive.